# Access request context in async code of vertx without passing it to each function

Tags: vert.x, requestcontext

I am developing an application in Vertx. I am attaching uniqueRequestId to each request and adds it to the `requestContext` object, so that while printing any logs I will associate uniqueRequestId to each log message and I will be able to better trace the request logs.

Now the one approach to this is, I can pass `requestContext` object to each function.

So my question is that, Is there any way to access `requestContext` object without passing it to each and every function?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [contextual logging for Vert.x 4](https://github.com/tsegismont/vertx-contextual-logging) (disclaimer: I created this library).

With Vert.x 3 you can only do it manually.

Comment: is there a version of the lib for 3.8.x?

Comment: @injecteer no, it relies on the tracing support introduced in 4.0